# Accessing XAML Keys in Template from Code Behind. (Image Based)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to tackle this one again, (from a previous post, but I had several issues that needed worked).

The goal here to generate a Number of buttons from scratch using a Template created in XAML. Each button is a Circle with a "simple icon" (PNG /w Alpha) and changes color with a hover. The issue I'm having is getting the Image to change per Button when its being generated. I cannot seem to access the x:Key Variables from XAML.It works right now rendering the default template (Image and Colors work). When I attempt to change the image to the new "icon" I want displayed, I can't seem to reference the x:Keys (cBG, cBGHi, id, idHi).

Here is my code, and some notes thereafter. Thanks in advance! :)

XAML

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="cBG" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="cBGHi" Color="#00AAFF"/>
<ImageSource x:Key="id">D:\32start.png</ImageSource>
<ImageSource x:Key="idHi">D:\32startHi.png</ImageSource>

<Style x:Key="UXButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property ="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name ="userControl" TargetType ="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <Ellipse Name ="bgg" Fill="{StaticResource cBG}" Margin="4"/>
                    <Image x:Name="UXImage" Width="32" Height="32" Source="{DynamicResource id}">
                        <Image.Clip>
                            <EllipseGeometry Center="16,16" RadiusX="16" RadiusY="16"/>
                        </Image.Clip>
                    </Image>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value ="True">
                        <Setter TargetName ="bgg" Property ="Fill" Value ="{StaticResource cBGHi}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName ="UXImage" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource idHi}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property ="IsPressed" Value ="True">
                        <Setter TargetName ="bgg" Property ="Fill" Value ="{StaticResource cBG}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName ="UXImage" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource id}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

C#.cs

```
private void BuildStack()
{
  Button b;
  Style UXStyle = (Style)FindResource("UXButton");

  // UXStyle.id = new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:\NewImage1.png", UriKind.Relative));
  // UXStyle.idHi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:\NewImage2.png", UriKind.Relative));

  b = new Button();
  b.Style = UXStyle;
  b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
  b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
  b.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
  b.Width = 48;
  b.Height = 48;
  UX.Children.Add(b);
}
```

//Notes

- The XAML is in a ResourceDictionary named "ButtonStyle.XAML" The
- Template is in XAML. The Button is generated in Code Behind.
- I can, and have in place, preRender Buttons that are used throughout the Program, but this section is special, as it is something of a "Recent" or "Favorite Files" kind of thing. Possibilities to make the icon match the string will be massive. (Think album art for songs, or start menu icons to shortcuts).
- I've Googled this up and down. Either, this is impossible or I don't know the nomenclature.
- I did find something called Binding or DataBinding, but I'm running into the same problem (accessing it in Code Behind).
- Thanks again!

Comment: I may have to come back to actually read all this, but at quick glance I'd wonder why not just set your button as the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl and pass in your values through dependency properties in the Item(in this case the button)?

Comment: @ChrisW. I have this written down to attempt while I'm trying to find out how Binding works. I learn best by example, but the MSDN is lacking. :(

Comment: Kind of like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481769/how-to-create-an-array-of-buttons-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **FindResource** or **TryFindResource**.

A good practice is to create a string constant which maps the name of your key in the resource dictionary.

```
this._image.Fill = (DrawingBrush)csd.FindResource("Image1DrawingBrush");



var resource = FindResource("userControl") as ControlTemplate;
```

Comment: I've attempted this and got the result:

An exception of type 'System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'userControl' resource not found.



// This comes back to the issue where the CodeBehind will not see Keys from the ResourceDictionary.